# Print out pattern using recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, draw, cout

I am trying to write a program that, given a natural number n, prints out the pattern that can be found [here](https://jutge.org/problems/P79860_en). So far, it only works well for n = 2.
I think my biggest problem is recognizing when the recursive function should call itself.
The code:

```
void print_line(int n) { // draw a line with n asterisks
    if (n == 0) return;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_bars(int n) { // draw the pattern
    if (n == 0) return;
    print_line(n);
    print_bars(n - 1);
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        print_bars(i);
    }
}
```

I'd prefer hints over the straigth answer. Thank you.

Comment: IT seems that last `for` loop is excessive.

Comment: As this is supposed to be a learning excercise, I don't want to give too much away. Are you sure that the end condition is your problem? What is your output and how is it wrong?

@Banzay, not for the problem as stated, but something is redundant.

Comment: Hint: after printing `**` you print `*`, `*`, after `***` you print `**` `*` `*`, `**` `*` `*`

Comment: Less cryptically: You print the (n-1)th *pattern* twice after the nth *line*

Comment: Not related to correctness: `std::string(n, '*')` is a string of n '*'s, you can replace all of `print_line` with `std::cout << std::string(n, '*') << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the exercise (which is presented in a awful way to my opinion), you should rethink your algorithm before your actual code. Every step can be thought as the previous step plus a piece, which in this case it's at the top, making everything much much easier. Forget your code and solve it from an abstract point of view first. HINT: the big mistake you did corresponds to the increment section of your second loop.

Once you did it, recode it. You can simply adjust one/two lines of code, but since it's a learning exercise, I would advise you to use recursion, which by the way is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I didn't properly consider what the actual pattern was. Instead I tried to mimic it by coding right away...
The resulting, working code:

```
void print_line(int n) { // draws a line with n asteriscs
    if (n == 0) return;
    cout << string(n, '*') << endl;
}

void print_bars(int n) { // draws the pattern
    if (n == 0) return;  
    print_line(n);
    print_bars(n - 1);
    print_bars(n - 1);
}
```